# Why is this infinite while loop not working

Tags: python

```
def main():

    import random

    guesslist = []
    ErrorTol = 5

    guessesTaken = 0



    print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")
    print("|                                                                    |")
    print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")                                                           
    print("|     WELCOME! Please enter your name to begin this guessing game    |")
    print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")
    print("|                                                                    |")
    print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")
    myName = input()

    again = ""

    while again != "q":

        number = random.uniform(-300, 300)
        print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between -300 and 300.')

        while guessesTaken < 3:
         print("Take a guess.") 
         guess = input()
         guess = int(guess)

         guesslist.append(guess) 

         guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

         if guess < number:
             print('Your guess is too low.')

         if guess > number:
             print('Your guess is too high.')

         if guess == number or (abs(number - guess) <= ErrorTol):
             break

        if guess == number or (abs(number - guess) <= ErrorTol):
         guessesTaken = guessesTaken
         print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')

         print("numbers you guessed:", guesslist)

        else:
         number = int(number)
         print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(number))

        again = input("Hit 'q' to quit the program or any other keys to play the game again.").lower()[0]

main()
```

I can't get the program to loop properly, I have no clue what I did wrong! When I do not guess the number correctly, I should be able to hit any keys to try again and hit 'q' to try again, but when I hit any other keys it will not loop properly. Again, I have no clue what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

You do not reset `guessesTaken` to zero so your program acts as if the user has already made there three guesses.  Try something like this:

```
    again = input("Hit 'q' to quit the program or any other keys to play the game again.").lower()[0]
    guessesTaken = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the amount of guesses when you check to see if the key is not equal to q. I put your code into another method, just better design!
Good luck!

```
import random
def main():

print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")
print("|                                                                    |")
print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")                                                           
print("|     WELCOME! Please enter your name to begin this guessing game    |")
print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")
print("|                                                                    |")
print("|--------------------------------------------------------------------|")

guess()
def guess():

guesslist = []
ErrorTol = 5

guessesTaken = 0
myName = input()

again = ""

while again != "q":
    guessesTaken = 0

    number = random.uniform(-300, 300)
    print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between -300 and 300.')

    while guessesTaken < 3:
     print("Take a guess.") 
     guess = input()
     guess = int(guess)

     guesslist.append(guess) 

     guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

     if guess < number:
         print('Your guess is too low.')

     if guess > number:
         print('Your guess is too high.')

     if guess == number or (abs(number - guess) <= ErrorTol):
         break

    if guess == number or (abs(number - guess) <= ErrorTol):
     guessesTaken = guessesTaken
     print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')

     print("numbers you guessed:", guesslist)

    else:
     number = int(number)
     print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(number))

    again = input("Hit 'q' to quit the program or any other keys to play the game again.")
```